# How to disable autoload packages in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget-package

In my solution folder in visual studio 2012 adds folder "packages" sometimes. And this folder strongly want to check in TFS.
Please help me to disable this feature.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376313/setting-up-a-common-nuget-packages-folder-for-all-solutions-when-some-projects-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated after the comment below:

That's a folder for Nuget packages. Folder gets added to the solution whenever you add the first Nuget package to any of your projects in the solution. 
2 things you need to do:

1) Right click on the folder in solution explorer and say `Exclude from Project`.

2) Then go to `Source Control Explorer` and right click on the packages folder and say delete. The Pending Change column should say "add" like the image below. It will be removed from source control once you do that but will stay in your local directory. Any changes you make after that in nugget packages will be done locally.

[image]

Comment: when i want to check in pending changes i should exclude this folder every time?

Comment: I have updated the answer so that you don't have to do everytime.