# Removing mkl_custom.dll from source control

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, ilnumerics

ILNumerics requires 2 native dlls to be loaded: `libiomp5md.dll" and "mkl_custom.dll". Previously, those dlls (and ILNumerics) were managed manually (in a seperated "lib" repository) but now we are going to switch to NuGet. Up to now from Nuget I can only get version 3.3.3 of ILNumerics, and it puts those dlls into folders "bin32" and "bin64".

But they are big. "mkl_custom.dll" is about 60M, and we will need both the 32 bit and 64 bit versions, so the total size is more than 120M. This will slow down "git clone" operations significantly. Also, our existing ".gitignore" policy file have a line "*.dll" to prevent any dlls being source controled.

We have enabled restoration of NuGet packages on build, but the restoration seems only created "bin32" and "bin64" folder, no dlls inside were restored.

So what can I do to restore those dlls after cloning a new repository or have the working tree cleaned up completely?

Ideally, I am looking for ways to tweak "NuGet.targets" file to allow proper restoration for ILNumerics. I know this is possible because I can simply uninstall and re-install ILNumerics from NuGet package manager interface to have those dlls restored. I just don't know where to start with.

We are using Visual Studio community 2013.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26368668/736079

Comment: The large size of the dependencies was one reason to switch to a new deployment scheme roughly a year ago. The nuget packages are now deprecated and will not receive updates anymore. We recommend to switch to [ILNumerics Ultimate VS](http://ilnumerics.net/download). It manages all this for you.