# Where to place NuGet

Tags: c#, nuget

I have downloaded Google WEB API sample project. Solution explorer contains .nuget folder that is missing on my machine. NuGet itself is installed on my system. Currently build project rices error:

> Error 1   This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on
>   this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For
>   more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105.
>   The missing file is
>   C:\pro\gplus-quickstart-csharp-master\.nuget\NuGet.targets.  C:\pro\gplus-quickstart-csharp-master\gplus-quickstart-csharp\gplus-quickstart-csharp.csproj    196 5   gplus-quickstart-csharp

[image]

If I remove .nuget folder I have the same error.

How to configure NuGet in my system to make project build?

Comment: Have you tried to enable NuGet Package Restore as it was suggested in error text and then just resore missing packages?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package Manager` and then selecting `Allow Nuget to download missing packages`?

Then rebuild your solution

Comment: I don't have "Nuget Package Manager" under Tools -> Options. How to get it there?

Comment: But I have "Packet Manager" and "Allow NuGet to download missing packages" and "Automatically check for missing packages during buid in Visual Studio" are checked

Comment: Which version of Visual studio do you have? If you don't have Nuget then you'll need to install it. https://docs.nuget.org/consume/installing-nuget

Comment: I use VS2013 and I have downloaded and installed NuGet for VS2013

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315756/enable-nuget-package-restore-on-visual-studio-2013 I think that might have some useful information