# nuget.config is ignored, specifically the repositoryPath

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

Visual Studio 2015 ignores my `nuget.config` that lies in the solution directory. This file has the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
  <repositoryPath>../packages/nuget</repositoryPath>
</settings>
```

Visual Studio however simply puts all packages into the packages folder in the solution directory.

This file has worked fine for years when using Visual Studio 2013. Am I missing something?

I am using the latest version of the NuGet extension (3.2)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like the format I used so far is no longer supported.

The following file works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="..\packages\nuget" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I wonder whether this new format is backward compatible with VS2013. Going to try tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, it does. As far as I can tell, this format has been available for years.

Comment: I added a nuget.config file to my solution and it did not work at first. I had to restart visual studio, and then it worked.

Comment: This solution helped me a lot. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: The value for repositoryPath will not accept $(SolutionDir) as part of a relative path.  But the value can contain environment variables, e.g.  %WORKING_COPY_TRUNK%\_packages".  For a relative path see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376313/setting-up-a-common-nuget-packages-folder-for-all-solutions-when-some-projects-a?rq=1