# How to us tfignore file for common nuget package folder?

Tags: version-control, tfs, nuget, nuget-package-restore, tfignore

I've setup TFS source control as follows to accommodate a project in multiple solutions to use NuGet package restore without the hint paths causing issues:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20660920/4354868

This NuGet repo structure works, my problem is that the .tfignore file is not working and I need some guidance on how to set up the .tfignore file to accommodate this 'common repo' structure.

Structure:

```
Root
   |-packages
   |-SharedProject
   |-Solution1
        -Uses SharedProject using Project Reference  
   |-Solution2
        -Uses SharedProject using Project Reference
```

Things I've tried:

.tfignore file at the root level, sibling to the "packages" folder I want to ignore with the following text:

```
packages
```

.tfignore in each solution root, pointing back up to the "packages" folder I want to ignore using the following text:

```
..\packages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `nuget.config` to the solution root with the option `disableSourceControlIntegration` set to true.

https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-settings

Comment: This is what I was missing. I didn't realize the Nuget.Config files could cascade, once I created the local nuget.config file to each of the solutions it worked as expected.