# How to setup single Nuget packages folder for multiple solutions and projects in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package-restore

We are developing multiple solutions in Visual Studio 2015. The solutions share some core projects that need nuget packages. The nuget references cannot be resolved when the nuget package is added from one solution and is later opened by another solution.

The folder structure is as follows:

- Codebase

  - SharedProjects

    - SharedProject1
  - SolutionA

    - WebProjectA
    - packages folder A
  - SolutionB

    - WebProjectB
    - packages folder B

When I install a nuget package to `SharedProject1` when `SolutionA` is opened, the dll reference shows the path to the `packages folder A`. When `SolutionB` is opened in another computer, `SharedProject1` has a reference error since the `packages folder A` doesn't exist.

I have read this solution: [Setting up a common nuget packages folder for all solutions when some projects are included in multiple solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376313/setting-up-a-common-nuget-packages-folder-for-all-solutions-when-some-projects-a) but this doesn't solve the problem since the `repositoryPath` key in the .nuget/NuGet.config file is not applied with `Visual Studio 2015` and `Nuget 3.4.3`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To resolve the issue, we put a NuGet.config file into the `Codebase` directory then deleted all the other Nuget.config files and .nuget folders in the solutions. Since NuGet configurations are propagated to sub folders, the settings in the single NuGet.config file are applied into all the solutions.

Inside the Nuget.config file we put the `packageSource`, `repositoryPath` settings.

Example NuGet.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="repositoryPath" value="./SharedPackages" />
    </config>
</configuration>
```

Existing nuget packages need to be uninstalled and reinstalled since the dll references in .csproj files will still show the old `packages` folder. Or you can manually edit the .csproj files.

Resulting folder structure:

- **Codebase** folder

  - Nuget.Config file
  - **SharedPackages** folder
  - **SharedProjects** folder

    - SharedProject1
  - **SolutionA** folder

    - WebProjectA
    - <s>packages folder A</s>
  - SolutionB

    - WebProjectB
    - <s>packages folder B</s>