# Configuring Nuget package path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget

We have the following folder structure for multiple solutions.

```
src
  solution1.sln
  solution2.sln
  solution3.sln
  \Solution1Projects
  \Solution2Projects
  \Solution3Projects
```

I would like nuget to download packages for `solution1` in `src\Solution1Projects\packages` and so on. How can I configure that?

Comment: What about solution2? Where should those packages go? src\Solution2Projects\packages? If so then that is not possible using a NuGet.Config file since all your solutions are in the same directory so they would share the same configuration for the packages directory.

Comment: @Victor, I agree with Matt's suggestion, yours are different from the general different solutions like this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37274599/how-to-setup-single-nuget-packages-folder-for-multiple-solutions-and-projects-in, since all sln files are in the same solution folder, I think we could create a shared package folder under the solution path, but not for every project folder.