# How to handle packages required for added DLL (not for current solution directly)

Tags: c#, nuget

There is one shared solution which uses packages (obtained via nuget, for example Elmah). This solution generates DLLs.

I have several solutions which want to use those dlls. I've added them via "Add reference".

This works when I have my nuget packages installed on every solution, but when i uninstall it from the descendant - it can't find it. I understand why (it does not copy folder with packages from sharedSolution, only generated DLLs), but I wonder what is best practice in such situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer to **manage the DLLs shared across multiple solutions manually**, the steps would be:

1. After loading the NuGet package to one of your solutions, navigate to the package location and copy all the required DLLs (with the supporting XML files, if any) to a separate folder (e.g. Vendors\SharedPackage.**Version1**).
2. Uninstall the NuGet package.
3. Now using "Add reference", navigate to the location where you copied the SharedPackage in step 1 (Vendors\SharedPackage.**Version1** folder) and add the required reference to all projects and solutions you want.

*Note:* If you go down this path, **you'll have to manage all the SharedPackage updates manually**: Get the updated package via NuGet, copy the package contents to a separate folder (Vendors\SharedPackage.**Version2**), uninstall the package, remove references to the old package from all your projects in all solutions, add references to the new version of the SharedPackage.

---

Alternatively, if you want to have your **NuGet packages managed by the Visual Studio**, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376313/setting-up-a-common-nuget-packages-folder-for-all-solutions-when-some-projects-a) is the best source of information I could find on this topic. [Vermis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/961484/vermis) has done a great research work!

*P.S.* Imho, the manual solution is easier to implement but harder to maintain. The decision is up to you.

Comment: I thought about the first solution, but I didn't like it. Thank You very much for clear and constructive answer!

Comment: Glad you found my post useful. Stay tuned with the VS and NuGet updates: sometimes they release new features that make our life easier.