# Build fails in azure with Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Vintasoft' could not be found

Tags: azure-devops

Locally building in VS2019 (on same hosted agent) is fine however, building from azure pipeline with self hosted agent(which is same hosted agent machine) is giving some issues.
Here is my pipeline yaml file

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
 name: 'default'
 vmImage: 'windSbx'

variables:
  solution: 'AmplifierWeb/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  name: BuildCode
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)" /p:OutputPath="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Repo contents:-

```
AmplifierWeb/ --AmplifierWeb.sln, AmplifierWeb.csproj.....
AmplifierAPI/......
azure-pipelines.yml
```

Build log snippet

```
23-04-14T18:34:05.6550002Z Project "C:\agent\_work\1\s\AmplifierWeb\AmplifierWeb.sln" (1) is building "C:\agent\_work\1\s\AmplifierWeb\AmplifierWeb.csproj" (8) on node 1 (default targets).
2023-04-14T18:34:05.6550563Z PrepareForBuild:
2023-04-14T18:34:05.6551720Z   Creating directory "obj\Debug\".
2023-04-14T18:34:06.1650815Z ResolveAssemblyReferences:
2023-04-14T18:34:06.1651655Z   Primary reference "Vintasoft.Imaging".
2023-04-14T18:34:06.1657520Z ##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Vintasoft.Imaging". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
2023-04-14T18:34:06.1659220Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Vintasoft.Imaging". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [C:\agent\_work\1\s\AmplifierWeb\AmplifierWeb.csproj]
2023-04-14T18:34:06.1659887Z           For SearchPath "{CandidateAssemblyFiles}".
2023-04-14T18:34:06.1660125Z           Considered "bin\Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.dll",
2023-04-14T18:34:06.1660402Z            but its name "Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data"
2023-04-14T18:34:06.1660637Z            didn't match the expected name "Vintasoft.Imaging".
2023-04-14T18:34:06.1661273Z           Considered "C:\agent\_work\1\s\AmplifierWeb\packages\IronPdf.Native.Chrome.Windows.2022.5.5614\build\net452\..\..\runtimes\win-x64\native\chrome_elf.dll",
2023-04-14T18:34:06.1684934Z            but its name "chrome_elf"
2023-04-14T18:34:06.1685152Z            didn't match the expected name "Vintasoft.Imaging".
2023-04-14T18:34:06.1709545Z           For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
2023-04-14T18:34:06.1709835Z           Considered "C:\agent\_work\1\s\AmplifierWeb\bin\Vintasoft.Imaging.dll", but it didn't exist.
2023-04-14T18:34:06.1710135Z           For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
2023-04-14T18:34:06.1710520Z           Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\Vintasoft.Imaging.winmd", but it didn't exist.
2023-04-14T18:34:06.1711588Z           Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\Vintasoft.Imaging.dll", but it didn't exist.
2023-04-14T18:34:06.1712154Z           Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\Vintasoft.Imaging.exe", but it didn't exist.
```

packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="BCrypt.Net-Next" version="4.0.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="HtmlAgilityPack" version="1.11.46" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="IronPdf" version="5.2.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="IronPdf.Native.Chrome.Windows" version="2022.5.5614" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="IronPdf.Slim" version="2022.5.5629" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" version="6.16.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="6.16.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="6.16.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="13.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Select.HtmlToPdf" version="22.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="SendGrid" version="9.28.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="starkbank-ecdsa" version="1.3.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="6.16.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="TimeZoneConverter" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

The AmplifierWeb.csproj snippet

```
<Reference Include="Vintasoft.Imaging, Version=12.1.6.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e553c7d3e075f61c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>bin\Vintasoft.Imaging.dll</HintPath>
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Vintasoft.Imaging.Annotation, Version=12.1.6.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e553c7d3e075f61c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>bin\Vintasoft.Imaging.Annotation.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Vintasoft.Imaging.Annotation.Pdf, Version=12.1.6.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e553c7d3e075f61c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>bin\Vintasoft.Imaging.Annotation.Pdf.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Vintasoft.Imaging.Annotation.Web.Api2Controllers, Version=12.1.6.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e553c7d3e075f61c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>bin\Vintasoft.Imaging.Annotation.Web.Api2Controllers.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I have copied the dll's and added reference manually Also changed the hint path (suggested here [MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70844151/msb3245-could-not-resolve-this-reference-could-not-locate-the-assembly) ) but it did not help.
Kindly suggest

Comment: After moving the vintasoft dll files to /Project/References , cleaning solution, add dlls as reference to the path  /Project/References ,& build the error is gone.